# Is there any specific frequency for a company to announce dividends?

Tags: dividends

I thought companies would announce dividends on a yearly basis. Is that correct?

Comment: By "specific" do you mean mandated by law or something else? I think all companies have an established frequency, and most of them are quarterly (every 3 months).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the US, most companies that pay a dividend pay on a quarterly basis.  There are a small number of companies that pay monthly and semi-annually.

Answer (score 0):

Most companies announce dividends once a year. It is not mandatory for companies to announce dividends during a certain period or even pay out dividends at all.  There are some companies like Apple or BP who announce and pay out a dividend each quarter.